# ASP.NET MVC EF and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider
And everything works as expected.

But now I want to add my model to the application, but I'm having problems to connect to create the database

Here one model Note.cs:

```
public class Note
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Done { get; set; }
    }
```

and here the the DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Note> Note { get; set; }

        static DataContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(
            new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());
        }
    }
```

and the the HomeController.cs:

```
private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var note = new Note { Id = 1, Text = "this is the text", Done = 0 };
            db.Note.Add(note);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Notes = db.Note.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

When I make the login everything is perfect, It creates the database for users.
But when I go to this controller I got this error on `db.Note.Add(note);`:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.
```

How can I make my code create the database according to the model?

Comment: could u remove DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>() and try aagain

Comment: and add new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<>()

Comment: later update-database

Comment: yes, I tried this before, exactly the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out the unsupported DbInitializers is the first step. I have done a test with your code and it works. You can get the working example from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C3D1C9304A2004EC!41405&authkey=!ALVEC1-W6weuur4&ithint=file%2czip). I have created the Note table by hand.